# Can I put an IF statement in a WHERE clause in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to put an IF statement in a WHERE CLAUSE?

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
WHERE QUANTITY NOT IN ('0') IF COLOUR NOT LIKE ('RED')
```

I am basically trying to exclude all orders with a quantity of 0 for all colours besides RED. Anyone know how I can achieve this in Snowflake? My above syntax doesn't work.

Comment: No, use regular AND/OR instead. Easier for the optimizer.

Comment: `WHERE (QUANTITY NOT IN ('0')) AND (COLOUR NOT LIKE ('RED'))`

Comment: WHERE COLOUR = 'RED' OR QUANTITY > 0

Answer (score 1):

`IF` statements are only valid in `SELECT` clauses. I'd recommend something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE other_condition
  AND (quantity != 0 OR colour = 'red')
```

The above will get you exactly what you need, with the option to add other conditions as required.

Answer (score 0):

As noted but others OR is the way to go:

```
SELECT *
FROM VALUES
    (0,'Red'), 
    (1,'Red'), 
    (0,'Blue'), 
    (1,'Blue')
    t(QUANTITY, COLOUR)
WHERE (t.COLOUR = 'Red' OR t.QUANTITY > 0);
```

gives:

| QUANTITY | COLOUR |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Red |
| 1 | Red |
| 1 | Blue |

to be silly, to prove you can use IFF in the WHERE clause this also works...

```
SELECT *
FROM VALUES
    (0,'Red'), 
    (1,'Red'), 
    (0,'Blue'), 
    (1,'Blue')
    t(QUANTITY, COLOUR)
WHERE IFF(t.COLOUR = 'Red' OR t.QUANTITY > 0, true, false);
```

| QUANTITY | COLOUR |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Red |
| 1 | Red |
| 1 | Blue |

And even the LIKE and IN logic can be used..

But given only one value is in the quantity `<>` or `!=` probably should be used, then there is also the point, quantity aka a number should be a number not text, and thus should not be compared to a string/text `'0'`. And LIKE is not case sensitive, thus perhaps to want ILIKE which is insenitive.

```
SELECT *
FROM VALUES
    (0,'Red'), 
    (1,'Red'), 
    (0,'Blue'), 
    (1,'Blue')
    t(QUANTITY, COLOUR)
WHERE (COLOUR LIKE ('Red') OR QUANTITY NOT IN ('0'))
```